# Is there any risks involved with changing a table's schema

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I want to know if there is any risks involved when changing a table's schema, for example from `dbo.` to `xyz.` or visa versa.

Would like to hear your views on this.

Answer (score 0):

First which crossed my mind is when you have views, stored procedures etc which contains query like

```
SELECT *
FROM [sch].[tbl]
```

Once you move table to new schema you will get 'Invalid object name 'oldSchema.tableName'.